# Biber \textasciicircum error

Tags: biblatex, biber, zotero

When exporting an article title containing a caret, like "10^30", Zotero outputs a .bib entry like the following:

```
@article{isles_what_1992,
    title = {What evidence is there that 2{\textasciicircum}65536 is a natural number?},
    journal = {Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic},
    author = {Isles, David}
}
@article{van_dantzig_is_1955,
    title = {Is 10{\textasciicircum}10{\textasciicircum}10 a Finite Number?},
    journaltitle = {Dialectica},
    author = {van Dantzig, D.}
}
```

It may be that this is incorrect behaviour by Zotero, but it appears to be attempting to escape the "^" character for consumption by Latex (I have the "Format: BibLaTeX" option selected when exporting).

When consumed by biber, these .bib entries lead to a .bbl file containing entries like the following:

```
  \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
  \field{journaltitle}{Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic}
  \field{title}{What evidence is there that 2{^}65536 is a natural number?}

  \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
  \field{journaltitle}{Dialectica}
  \field{title}{Is 10{^}10{^}10 a Finite Number?}
```

Which leads to Latex (or BibLaTeX) throwing a series of "Missing $ inserted", "Missing { inserted", "Missing $ inserted" etc errors - the same errors Latex throws if it meets "10{^}10" in normal text.

My question is which part of the chain here is misbehaving, and what should I do about it? I can manually edit the .bib file, or the .bbl file, but don't want to have to do that every time I edit the list of references.

Comment: if biber is converting `\textasciicircum` to `^` then I'd say that is a bug. (you could work round it by setting `\catcode\`\^=12` and then using `\sp` if you need a superscript

Comment: I agree that this is a bug. Please report this at the bug tracker https://github.com/plk/biber/issues. In the meantime you can try to use `\^{}`, Biber does not convert this command.

Comment: Better yet, fix the wrong `2{\textasciicircum}65536` into the correct `$2^{65536}$`. The original title in the van Dantzig paper has `$10^{10^{10}}$`, see http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1746-8361.1955.tb01332.x/full (access to the other paper is impossible ATM).

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1305/ndjfl/1093634481 indeed has the caret in the title: ["2^65536"](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093634481)

Comment: On the Zotero end, entering the title as `What evidence is there that 2<sup>65536</sup> is a natural number?` should produce the presumably correct 
`title = {What evidence is there that 2^{65536} is a natural number?},` in BibLaTeX

Comment: I could see [Isles’ paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093634481) and it indeed has a literal `2^65536` in the title (contrary to the other paper that has `$10^{10^{10}}$`.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug with Biber's character conversion. It has been reported (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/219) and will be resolved in Biber 2.12.